# Installation failure of imagemagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick

I am trying to install imagemagick gem in Ruby on Rails:

> ImageMagick 7.0.2-9 Q16 i686 2016-08-26 http://www.imagemagick.org
>   Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2016 ImageMagick
>   Studio LLC License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
>   Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP Delegates (built-in): bzlib jbig jng jpeg lzma png tiff xml zlib

`indiba@indiba2:~$     apt-get install php5-imagick`

> E: Could
>   not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
>   E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are
>   you root?

`indiba@indiba2:~$     service php5-fpm restart php5-fpm`

> unrecognized service

`indiba@indiba2:~$     dpkg -r imagemagick-6.9.0`

> dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege

Comment: Can you clearly show what the error is? Just not understandable.

Comment: Just follow the instruction will help you [Install](https://gist.github.com/rodleviton/74e22e952bd6e7e5bee1)

Comment: Is your issue has been solved or still have ?

Comment: it should be `sudo apt-get install php5-imagick`

Comment: @VKatz it is not resolved .

Comment: @VKatz I tried as per your instruction but it is showing an error root@indiba2:~# wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick-6.8.7-7.tar.gz
--2016-09-01 12:29:42--  http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick-6.8.7-7.tar.gz
Resolving www.imagemagick.org (www.imagemagick.org)... 198.72.81.86
Connecting to www.imagemagick.org (www.imagemagick.org)|198.72.81.86|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2016-09-01 12:29:43 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Comment: try with this [https://www.enovate.co.uk/web-design-blog/2015/02/25/how-to-install-imagemagick-from-source-on-ubuntu-14.04](link)